How to simulate ESP32 camera board?
I couldn't find any ESP32 Camera board simulator online, even popular embedded systems simulator like wokwi didn't provide.
Perhaps you can tell me if there is any existing ESP32 Camera Board online.
The reason I asked this, because I'm so tired to debug embedded systems where I need to compiling and then uploading the program for small code changes.
My code base currently on C language where I'm using Espressif IoT Development Framework (FreeRTOS).
I ever heard that ESP32 Camera Board basically just a normal ESP32 but with reserved pinout for camera pins.
Here is the reserved pin map:



OV2640
ESP32
Variable name in code




D0
GPIO 5
Y2_GPIO_NUM


D1
GPIO 18
Y3_GPIO_NUM


D2
GPIO 19
Y4_GPIO_NUM


D3
GPIO 21
Y5_GPIO_NUM


D4
GPIO 36
Y6_GPIO_NUM


D5
GPIO 39
Y7_GPIO_NUM


D6
GPIO 34
Y8_GPIO_NUM


D7
GPIO 35
Y9_GPIO_NUM


XCLK
GPIO 0
XCLK_GPIO_NUM


PCLK
GPIO 22
PCLK_GPIO_NUM


VSYNC
GPIO 25
VSYNC_GPIO_NUM


HREF
GPIO 23
HREF_GPIO_NUM


SDA
GPIO 26
SIOD_GPIO_NUM


SCL
GPIO 27
SIOC_GPIO_NUM


POWER PIN
GPIO 32
PWDN_GPIO_NUM



Since there is no ESP32 Camera Board to simulate, i'm wondering if I can simulate based on those physical pin.
So, there are two esp32 board total, the first one act as esp32cam board, and the second one act as camera module where it virtually sending frame buffer to those reserved pin. Esp32 that act as camera module will get the framebuffer from wifi interface or IP.
Hence, I can code with existing esp32 camera pinout.
The overall diagram will be like
this:
Framebuffer (IP) -> ESP32 (act as camera module) -> ESP32 (act as camera board) -> Printing Framebuffer

So, how do I achieve my goal?

Have you tried Wowki? https://wokwi.com/projects/361653364762592257


The reason I asked this, because I'm so tired to debug embedded systems where I need to compiling and then uploading the program for small code changes.
Lol. That's how it works, mate.


@liaifat85 what the program does? I never heard Node-RED config, what is it?

@MuhammadIkhwanPerwira I think YOUR_NODE_RED_PORT is for the connection to a Node-RED server. I haven't used it myself, but Questions tagged node-red on StackOverflow might help.

As far as I analyze, the Node-RED server receives the image data from the ESP32-CAM and can process it further depending on the user's configuration. So, it's still not achieve what I expect where ESP32 Cam that simulating OV2640 module, tries to simulating RGB data being sent with D0 to D7 pins.

OV2640 – Specs, Datasheets, Cameras, Features, Alternatives says for the OV2640 camera:

The sensor interface is DVP which standards for digital video port, a kind of parallel source synchronization camera interface with 8bit data, horizontal/vertical synchronization signal, and an associated pixel clock

The ESP32 Camera board uses a ESP32-S2. Looking at the ESP32-S2 Series Datasheet and ESP32S2 Technical Reference Manual the camera interface is receive only. E.g. the I2S0I_H_SYNC, I2S0I_V_SYNC and I2S0I_H_ENABLE signals are shown as input only in the DVP camera mode.
Therefore, can't see how one ESP32 Camera board can be configured to transmit a camera image to another ESP32 Camera board connected via the DVP camera interface.
